# Sprintf equivalent in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I don't know why Wikipedia [lists Mathematica as a programming language with printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Programming_languages_with_printf).  I just couldn't find the equivalent in Mathematica.

My specific task is to process a list of data files with padded numbers, which I used to do it in bash with

```
fn=$(printf "filename_%05d" $n)
```

The closest function I found in Mathematica is `PaddedForm`.  And after some trial and error, I got it with

```
"filename_" <> PaddedForm[ Round@#, 4, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""} ]&
```

It is very odd that I have to use the number 4 to get the result similar to what I get from "%05d".  I don't understand this behavior at all.  Can someone explain it to me?

And is it the best way to achieve what I used to in bash?

Comment: That's bizarre - I was never aware of a printf equivalent in Mathematica. I've used PaddedForm (and all kinds of precision control) stuff plenty before. I've also stared at the PaddedForm documentation plenty trying to figure out about that extra character of padding. +1. I want to know.

Comment: My theory is that Wikipedia lists Mathematica as a language with printf because it has StringForm. But StringForm is a sad, pale shadow of printf.

Comment: [`IntegerString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerString.html)

Comment: Since this old question popped up again why doesn't somebody go fix the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't use `PaddedForm` for this. In fact, I'm not sure that `PaddedForm` is good for much of anything. Instead, I'd use good old `ToString`, `Characters` and `PadLeft`, like so:

```
toFixedWidth[n_Integer, width_Integer] := 
  StringJoin[PadLeft[Characters[ToString[n]], width, "0"]]
```

Then you can use `StringForm` and `ToString` to make your file name:

```
toNumberedFileName[n_Integer] :=
  ToString@StringForm["filename_``", toFixedWidth[n, 5]]
```

Mathematica is not well-suited to this kind of string munging.

**EDIT to add:** Mathematica proper doesn't have the required functionality, but the `java.lang.String` class has the static method `format()` which takes `printf`-style arguments. You can call out to it using Mathematica's JLink functionality pretty easily. The performance won't be very good, but for many use cases you just won't care that much:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
LoadJavaClass["java.lang.String"];
LoadJavaClass["java.util.Locale"];
sprintf[fmt_, args___] :=
 String`format[Locale`ENGLISH,fmt,
  MakeJavaObject /@
   Replace[{args},
    {x_?NumericQ :> N@x,
     x : (_Real | _Integer | True | 
         False | _String | _?JavaObjectQ) :> x,
     x_ :> MakeJavaExpr[x]},
    {1}]]
```

You need to do a little more work, because JLink is a bit dumb about Java functions with a variable number of arguments. The `format()` method takes a format string and an array of Java `Object`s, and Mathematica won't do the conversion automatically, which is what the `MakeJavaObject` is there for.

Comment: This is indeed very complicated procedure for a simple printf function.

Comment: Tiny bug there:  "w" instead of "width".

Comment: Thanks for the java function.  It looks like the best we can have.

Answer (score 8):

I've run into the same problem quite a bit, and decided to code my own function. I didn't do it in Java but instead just used string operations in Mathematica. It turned out quite lengthy, since I actually also needed %f functionality, but it works, and now I have it as a package that I can use at any time. Here's a link to the GitHub project:

https://github.com/vlsd/MathPrintF

It comes with installation instructions (really just copying the directory somewhere in the $Path).

Hope this will be helpful to at least some.

Answer (score 5):

You could also define a function which passes all arguments to StringForm[] and use IntegerString or the padding functions as previously mentioned:

```
Sprintf[args__] := StringForm[args__] // ToString;
file = Sprintf["filename_``", IntegerString[n, 10, 5]];
```

Answer (score 2):

[`IntegerString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerString.html) does exactly what you need. In this case it would be

```
IntegerString[x,10,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Pillsy.
Here's how I would do it.
Note the handy `cat` function, which I think of as kind of like sprintf (minus the placeholders like StringForm provides) in that it works like Print (you can print any concatenation of expressions without converting to String) but generates a string instead of sending to stdout.

```
cat = StringJoin@@(ToString/@{##})&;

pad[x_, n_] := If[StringLength@cat[x]>=n, cat[x], 
                                          cat@@PadLeft[Characters@cat[x],n,"0"]]

cat["filename_", pad[#, 5]]&
```

This is very much like Pillsy's answer but I think `cat` makes it a little cleaner.
Also, I think it's safer to have that conditional in the pad function -- better to have the padding wrong than the number wrong.