# How to print an integer with n leading zeros in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I tried to do the following :

```
Do[
  f1 = StringReplace[
    "obsxxxx.out", {"xxxx" -> ToString[i]}];
  Print[f1];
  ,
  {i, 200}];
```

and obtain

```
obs0001.out
obs0002.out
...
obs0010.out
...
obs0100.out
...
```

and so on.

I tried that:

```
ToString[Flatten[IntegerDigits[20, 10, 4]]]
```

but I still have a list ...

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question

Comment: see also [Sprintf equivalent in Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1526617/211232).

Comment: You need a `FromDigits` outside the `ToDigits`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Perhaps you require something like:

```
Table[IntegerString[i, 10, 4], {i, 1, 10}]
```

giving

```
{"0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006", "0007", "0008", 
"0009", "0010"}
```

or

```
Table["obs" <> IntegerString[i, 10, 4] <> ".out", {i, 1, 10}]
```

giving

> {"obs0001.out", "obs0002.out", "obs0003.out", "obs0004.out", 
>   "obs0005.out", "obs0006.out", "obs0007.out", "obs0008.out", 
>   "obs0009.out", "obs0010.out"}